# PHP MYSQL Combine two queries on one line

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database where everyone who books onto a course is assigned a '70' in the status column, anyone who cancels in given a '10'.

I want a report on everyone who is booked on a course eliminating those who have cancelled.

The problem is everyone retains the number, so the query below shows everyone.
I would like to remove everyone who has a 10 regardless of the fact they've got a 70 also.

```
WHERE statuscode <>'10'
AND statuscode <>'20'
AND statuscode <>'30'
AND statuscode <>'40'
AND statuscode <>'50'
AND statuscode <>'60'
AND statuscode ='70'
AND statuscode <>'80'
AND statuscode <>'90'
AND statuscode <>'100'
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure please? I suspect a `where exists` clause or a `having` clause can help.

Comment: Don't get your question. as what @Kisaragi mentioned, please do so. unless you have only 1 column name "statuscode"?

Comment: Do you store integer values in a character column?

Comment: The system is moodle but the report is stand alone. the column is statuscode which is the activity code when some one books on a course, 70 = booked up, 10 = cancelled the other numbers mean attended or no show ect. someone will book on a course and a row is added with a 70, if they cancel a new row will be added with a 10, so they will have 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE statuscode ='70' AND MOD(CAST(statuscode as unsigned),10)=0
```

UPDATE:

The subselect returns ids of all users who cancelled (status code=10) so we remove all for the ids.

```
DELETE
FROM the_table t
where id in (select id from the_table t where statuscode='10')
```

Comment: It still shows everyone with a 70. the main issue is the persons name is duplicated in the table one row with a 70 then another separate row with a 10.

Comment: I'm back on the report again.. I'd be happy with putting the word cancelled in a column instead of the '10'.  Is there an IF statuscode='10' THEN 'cancelled' type statement. or IF statuscode='70' THEN 'booked' else 'cancelled'.

Answer (score 0):

I've settled for a work around.  I've created a new table with two columns with the codes and words in.  Joined them together and displayed the words.